# Build an embedded setup with custom QT/X11 application as desktop background

Tags: x11, qt

I am writing a custom application in QT5 (for X11), which will be used in an embedded setup. When the system boots, I want the system to boot into my application, with the main window of my application being effectively the desktop background, any other windows should open on top of it and should have normal window management facilities available.

The system is based on Debian buster, how do I put the peices together to make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few peices to this puzzle, a greeter (I used sddm), a window manager (I used openbox) and the application itself.

First the application itself, we need to tell the window manager that our window is the desktop background, this was the hardest bit to find details on, but eventually looking at the source for pcmanfm-qt, some experimenting and googling one of the constants in it led me to a [question over on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992144/making-a-window-a-desktop-in-xlib-qt). I ended up with the following code in the constructor for my main window. I placed this code behind a command line parameter so it was also still possible to run the application in the conventional way.

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_X11NetWmWindowTypeDesktop);
setFixedSize(QApplication::desktop()->size());
```

Note: I initially had "resize" instead of setFixedSize, that worked until I tried to use a layout manger at which point the layout manager decided to expand my "desktop window" so it wouldn't fit on the screen.

To tie together the greeter, window manager and my application required defining a custom "session", I did this was two files, the first of which was a shell script at /usr/bin/starthhs

```
#!/bin/bash
openbox --startup '/home/ubilinux/cvx86/gui asdesktop'
```

The second was a "desktop file" at /usr/share/xsessions/handheldhyperspec.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=starthhs
TryExec=starthhs
Name=Handheld hyperspec 
Comment=Handheld hyperspec
```

Finally I needed to configure the greeter to autologin to my newly defined session. To do this I created a file /etc/sddm.conf.d/autologin with the following contents.

```
[Autologin]
User=root
Session=handheldhyperspec.desktop
Relogin=
```